# Rails asynchronous POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, asynchronous

I'm wondering if there is a way of doing a post request in rails that does not wait for the response, which means in asynchronous.

I want to do such a call in a controller. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way you'd generally accomplish this in Rails is to use a background worker like Resque or DelayedJob to do your heavy lifting. You would post to an endpoint, and queue up some long-running job as a result of that post. The request will finish quickly, and then your background worker will asynchronously do the slow/heavy work.

Rails, in general, is not designed for asynchronous work like EventMachine or Node.js. You have options to get that sort of behavior, but it's not as easy as just setting a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) and an on complete handler

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://localhost:3000/posts/1.json")
request.on_complete do |response|
   # your stuff
end
```